VSCode executeCommand('git.stage) does not stage file
I am trying to make a git extension for VSCode.
I am attempting to use the gitExtensions API. however it has terrible documentation.
I am able to get a file from the gitExtensionsAPI, however I am unable to do anything with it.
can someone tell me why this does not work?
"git.stage" is supposed to accept files to stage as parameters
  const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.git').exports.getAPI(1)

  const repo = gitExtension.repositories[0]

  const unstaged =  repo.state.workingTreeChanges

  const fileToStage = repo.state.workingTreeChanges[0];

  vscode.commands.executeCommand('git.stage', fileToStage);

this code does not stage the file.
any suggestions on how to stage or unstage a file would be appreciated

after much trial and error i found the solution to the problem.
the git commands in VSCode accept SourceControlResourceStates as arguments.
async clean(...resourceStates: SourceControlResourceState[]): Promise<void>{
the issue is that the resource that is provided by repo.state.workingTreeChanges is a wrapper, which is a little strange, which contains the SourceControlResourceState under the property .resource so the answer to this question is:
vscode.commands.executeCommand('git.stage', fileToStage.resource );
passes the correct object to the command
